# Why is there an NA introduction in the code for clustering?

Tags: r, error-handling, cluster-analysis

The code is an attempt to write a clustering code for binary variables, using the simple dissimilarity measure (i.e. for places where a 0-0 match is a perfect match). In order to make sure it does not end on a local minima, i need to run this several times. But occasionally, I end up with an error message pertaining to the introduction of a NA value. There are no coercions used in the code. I don't know how the NA value crops up.

```
dissim<-function(a,b){
match<-sum(a==b)
unmatch<-sum(a!=b)
sim<-match/(match+unmatch)
dissim<-1-sim
return(dissim)
}

findmode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}


pleasecluster<-function(df){
  ##create will create the first prototypes i.e. initial cluster centres. First prototype is random, second is the centre farthest from it.
  create<-function(dataframe){
    proto1<-NULL
    for(i in 1:length(dataframe[1,])){
      proto1<-c(proto1, sample(c(0,1), 1))
    }
    proto2<-as.numeric(proto1==0)
    return(list(proto1, proto2))
  }
  ##This function will assign a cluster index to each entry in the original data frame. 
  clusterassign<-function(proto1, proto2, dataframe){
    clustervector<-NULL
    for(i in 1:length(dataframe[,1])){
      dis1<-dissim(dataframe[i,], proto1)
      dis2<-dissim(dataframe[i,], proto2)
      clusterindex<-which.min(c(dis1, dis2))
      clustervector<-c(clustervector, clusterindex)
    }
    return(clustervector)
  }
  ##Based on the created clusters, this will then find the centres of those clusters
  updproto<-function(clvec, dataframe){
    cluster1<-(dataframe[clvec==1,])
    cluster2<-(dataframe[clvec==2,])
    newproto1<-NULL
    newproto2<-NULL
    for(i in 1:length(dataframe[1,])){
      mode1<-findmode(cluster1[,i])
      newproto1<-c(newproto1, mode1)
      mode2<-findmode(cluster2[,i])
      newproto2<-c(newproto2, mode2)
    }
    return(list(newproto1, newproto2))
  }
  ##This will match the centres found of the current clusters and the initial centres used
  checkproto<-function(oldproto1, olproto2, newproto1, newproto2){
    if (sum(oldproto1!=newproto1)>0){a1<-FALSE}
    else{a1<-TRUE}
    if (sum(oldproto2!=newproto2)>0){a2<-FALSE}
    else{a2<-T}
    return(c(a1,a2))
  }
  ##The main function
  starter<-create(df)
  proto1<-starter[[1]]
  proto2<-starter[[2]]
  count<-1
  repeat{
  clvec<-clusterassign(proto1, proto2, df)
  oldproto1<-proto1
  oldproto2<-proto2
  upd<-updproto(clvec, df)
  proto1<-upd[[1]]
  proto2<-upd[[2]]
  check<-checkproto(oldproto1, oldproto2, proto1, proto2)
  count<-count+1
 #calc total dissimilarity 
  totdiss1<-NULL
  totdiss2<-NULL
  cluster1<-df[clvec==1,]
  for(i in 1:sum(clvec==1)){

   dissi1<-dissim(cluster1[i,],proto1)
   totdiss1<-sum(totdiss1, dissi1)
  }
  cluster2<-df[clvec==2,]
  for(i in 1:sum(clvec==2)){

    dissi2<-dissim(cluster2[i,],proto2)
    totdiss2<-sum(totdiss2, dissi2)
  }
  totdiss<-totdiss1+totdiss2
  if((all(check))|count>50){break}
  }

  return(list(oldproto1, oldproto2, clvec, count, totdiss, totdiss1, totdiss2 ))
}
```

for a test dataset, I got the correct value and the error message.

```
a
  c.1..1. c.1..0. c.1..1..1 c.0..0. c.0..0..1 c.0..0..2 c.1..1..2 c.1..1..3
1       1       1         1       0         0         0         1         1
2       1       0         1       0         0         0         1         1
3       1       1         1       1         0         0         1         1
4       1       1         1       0         0         0         1         1
5       1       1         0       0         0         0         1         1
6       0       0         0       1         1         1         1         1
7       0       1         0       1         1         1         1         1
8       0       0         0       1         1         1         1         1
9       0       0         0       1         0         1         1         1

pleasecluster(a)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 0.625

[[6]]
[1] 0.375

[[7]]
[1] 0.25

pleasecluster(a)
Error in if (sum(oldproto2 != newproto2) > 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

PLease let me know if this is more suited to code-review or data-science SE.

ADDENDUM

Considering, that the error may arise due to cases where one of the clusters would be empty (leading to NA values whenever a row is called), I modified the code. (I also modified the length for which all the for loops were running using ncol and nrow). Now I get a different error.

```
findmode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}


pleasecluster<-function(df){
  ##create will create the first prototypes i.e. initial cluster centres. First prototype is random, second is the centre farthest from it.
  create<-function(dataframe){
    repeat{proto1<-NULL
    for(i in 1:ncol(dataframe)){
      proto1<-c(proto1, sample(c(0,1), 1))
    }
    proto2<-as.numeric(proto1==0)
    if (length(unique(proto1))>1){break}
    }
    return(list(proto1, proto2))
  }
  ##This function will assign a cluster index to each entry in the original data frame. 
  clusterassign<-function(proto1, proto2, dataframe){
    clustervector<-NULL
    for(i in 1:nrow(dataframe)){
      dis1<-dissim(dataframe[i,], proto1)
      dis2<-dissim(dataframe[i,], proto2)
      clusterindex<-which.min(c(dis1, dis2))
      clustervector<-c(clustervector, clusterindex)
    }
    return(clustervector)
  }
  ##Based on the created clusters, this will then find the centres of those clusters
  updproto<-function(clvec, dataframe){
    cluster1<-(dataframe[clvec==1,])
    cluster2<-(dataframe[clvec==2,])
    newproto1<-NULL
    newproto2<-NULL
    if (nrow(cluster2)>0&nrow(cluster1)>0) {for(i in 1:ncol(dataframe)){
      mode1<-findmode(cluster1[,i])
      newproto1<-c(newproto1, mode1)
      mode2<-findmode(cluster2[,i])
      newproto2<-c(newproto2, mode2)
    }}
    else {starter<-create(dataframe)
    newproto1<-starter[[1]]
    newproto2<-starter[[2]]}
    return(list(newproto1, newproto2))
  }
  ##This will match the centres found of the current clusters and the initial centres used
  checkproto<-function(oldproto1, olproto2, newproto1, newproto2){
    if (sum(oldproto1!=newproto1)>0){a1<-FALSE}
    else{a1<-TRUE}
    if (sum(oldproto2!=newproto2)>0){a2<-FALSE}
    else{a2<-T}
    return(c(a1,a2))
  }
  ##The main function
  starter<-create(df)
  proto1<-starter[[1]]
  proto2<-starter[[2]]
  count<-1
  repeat{
  clvec<-clusterassign(proto1, proto2, df)
  oldproto1<-proto1
  oldproto2<-proto2
  upd<-updproto(clvec, df)
  proto1<-upd[[1]]
  proto2<-upd[[2]]
  check<-checkproto(oldproto1, oldproto2, proto1, proto2)
  count<-count+1
 #calc total dissimilarity 
  totdiss1<-NULL
  totdiss2<-NULL
  cluster1<-df[clvec==1,]
  for(i in 1:nrow(cluster1)){

   dissi1<-dissim(cluster1[i,],proto1)
   totdiss1<-sum(totdiss1, dissi1)
  }
  cluster2<-df[clvec==2,]
  for(i in 1:nrow(cluster2)){

    dissi2<-dissim(cluster2[i,],proto2)
    totdiss2<-sum(totdiss2, dissi2)
  }
  totdiss<-totdiss1+totdiss2
  if((all(check))|count>50){break}
  }

  return(list(oldproto1, oldproto2, clvec, count, totdiss, totdiss1, totdiss2 ))
}




pleasecluster(a)
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in e2[[j]] : subscript out of bounds 
3 Ops.data.frame(a, b) 
2 dissim(cluster2[i, ], proto2) 
1 pleasecluster(a)
```

Comment: You should have gotten an error message when you attempted to use the `create` function. It's not going to be in the `globalenv()`.

Comment: @42- This error message crops up in rare renditions of the script. How could it then be due to an inappropriate assignment of environments? I did not get how could not being in .glodalenv() cause a problem.

Comment: @42- Sorry, but learning R on my own. Hence I might not know what would otherwise be pretty common knowledge!

Comment: I thought that the function would not be avaiable but apparently I was wrong. I set `options(error=recover)` and looked at values at the time of the error.  `upd[[2]]` has NA's at the time the error is thrown. You need to look at the reasons why htat might be occurring.

Comment: @42- I think I solved the problem. Should I self answer or delete the question?

Comment: Self answers are welcome on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that occasionally the cluster vector turns out to be all 1's or all 2's, so that one of the clusters is empty. Hence, in the further loop, when these empty clusters are called, there's either the introduction of `NA's` or, as in the second case, the calling fails since the cluster is empty. A simple randomising loop in case such thing crops up in the `clusterassign` function should solve the problem.

```
#to check for and remove empty clusters
     if (length(unique(clustervector))==1){
      repeat{ clustervector<-NULL
      for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe)){
        add<-sample(c(1,2), 1)
        clustervector<-c(clustervector, add)
      }
      if (length(unique(clustervector))==2){break}
      }
    }
```